# Create object from JSON response remove unwanted key-values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting JSON response as below :

```
bills : [
             {
                id: '111',
                date: '22 Jan 2020',
                amount: -250.00
            },
            {
                id: '222',
                date: '08 Jan 2020',
                amount: 700.00
            },
            {
                id: '333',
                date: '08 Feb 2020',
                amount: -250.00
            },
            {
                id: '788-609098-129169487',
                date: '08 Feb 2020',
                amount: 120.00
            }
    ]
```

I want to have object with only `date` and `amount` with `month`-wise total of `amount` like :

```
{
    "Jan" :
    {
        "month" : "Jan",
        "amount"  : 450.00
    },
    "Feb" :
    {
        "month" : "Feb",
        "amount"  : -130.00
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Why do you use the month twice? Once as a key, once as a value?
Why not using an array like :
 ``` 
[
    {
        "month" : "Jan",
        "amount"  : 450.00
    },
    {
        "month" : "Feb",
        "amount"  : -130.00
    }
]
```

Comment: @Shiladitya I did checked that one but we're also adding the amounts' not just deleting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const bills =  [
    {
       id: '111',
       date: '22 Jan 2020',
       amount: -250.00
   },
   {
       id: '222',
       date: '08 Jan 2020',
       amount: 700.00
   },
   {
       id: '333',
       date: '08 Feb 2020',
       amount: -250.00
   },
   {
       id: '788-609098-129169487',
       date: '08 Feb 2020',
       amount: 120.00
   }
];

const output = bills.reduce((a, {date, amount}) => {
    const month = date.slice(3, 6);

    if(!a[month]) { 
        a[month] = {"month": month, amount} 
    } else { 
        a[month].amount += amount ;
    }
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Amount is wrong. The first value gets added twice. This should solve:  
`if(!a[month]) {
        a[month] = {"month": month, amount}
    } else {
a[month].amount += amount;
    }`

Comment: @LearningEveryday - Thanks a lot.

Comment: @random Is it possible to return array of objects instead of object of objects ?

Comment: @Veey - Yes. Use `Object.values()` on the final result of reduce. i:e `Object.values(output)`.